# Why doesn't the word "but" mean the oppositional relationship in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

I've read a sentence from the *Economist*, as follows:

> THE LATEST monthly employment report, published on April 2nd, painted an impressive picture: over the previous month America created more than 900,000 jobs. That figure, the strongest since August, reflects the state of the economy in the first half of March, when the surveys took place. **But** a look at “high-frequency” economic data for more recent weeks, on everything from daily restaurant diners to Google-search behaviour, suggests that, since then, the recovery has if anything accelerated further. America’s post-lockdown boom has begun.

I couldn't see the negation meaning in the word "But". Because I think the two sentences which is before and after "But" both mean that the economy was developing very well, and the word "but" seems not to mean oppositional relationship. I wonder whether it should be replaced by the word "and"?

Comment: The opposition is this: The economy has developed not _well_, but _very well_.

Comment: "But" doesn't require negation: it has weaker meanings given as "on the other hand", "notwithstanding", where there's an element of contrast but no antithesis, with the meaning as psmears says. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but

Comment: 'But' here is used in the 'contrasting lesser with greater' sense. 'But more than this, ...' _[OK /Granted,] John has a Jag. But Jill has a Bugatti._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English conjunction *but* is not a negative, nor does it imply opposition. It is in fact the same logical conjunction as *and* -- any sentence that is true with *but* will also be true with *and* substituted for *but*.

- *Frank left but Mary stayed behind*  =  *Frank left and Mary stayed behind.*

[Logicians](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/logicguide.pdf) ignore the difference profitably: there is a logical functor called *And* -- and two functors called *Or* -- and none called *But*. It's not needed for truth values, which is all that logic is good for.

The difference between *but* and *and* is that *but* carries a special [presupposition](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/presuptrig.pdf) of surprise. Someone who says "A but B" instead of just "A and B" finds something surprising about B -- there is some aspect that the speaker would not have predicted, or would not have expected the listener to predict.

That's not a difference of meaning, really; presuppositions are pragmatic differences, about a  subliminal expression of the speaker's beliefs and expectations, rather than the truth or falsity of the proposition.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest sense of **but** I've found in any dictionary is one given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/but):

> Used to introduce a response expressing a feeling such as surprise ...
> anger [esteem, satisfaction, even smugness].
>
> - *But that's an incredible saving!*
> - *We did not know what to expect, but what a fantastic surprise night, it was a real thrill.*

Here, but is used in the 'contrasting a lesser with a [far] greater, awesome perhaps' sense. A may be big, but B is huge. It signals a trumping of the first statement.

'But more than this, ...'

- *[OK /Granted,] John has a Jag. But Jill has a Bugatti.*

Or from Red Dwarf [episode *Justice*] [[All the Tropes; adjusted](https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/I_Lied)]:

> [Lister and the Simulant agree to come unarmed to "talk"]:
>
> - Simulant: *Guess what?* (Pulls out hunting knife.) *I lied.*
> - Lister: *Guess what?* (Allows metal bar to slide from the arm of his jacket.) *So did I*.
> - Simulant: *But I lied twice*. (Pulls out a blaster.)